Plesk Server Issue NodeJs 403 Forbidden Issue. Passenger is not running
I have been trying to run nodeJs Application on plesk server. Now Node is running on port:3000. But when I hit the "passenger status". It give me result of
"Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone is not running, according to PID file /root/passenger.3000.pid".
Now I don't know, The 403 Forbidden error I facing due to passenger is not enabled or permission. As I already given permission to my files.
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
